# SSH passwords & Special Characters

Tags: ssh, password

Can anyone provide a reference that describes the use of special characters with ssh passwords during the ssh-keygen process, e.g. such characters as @ symbol? I understand at this point that using passwords with some special characters does not work; however, I would like to understand why it doesn't. My guess is that it has much to do with POSIX standards.

Comment: What makes you think that some "symbols" would not work in SSH passwords?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I have come to that conclusion because once I changed a password without an @ symbol I was able to complete my ssh login to my server.

Comment: Are you at liberty to disclose the client (and server) platforms and versions? This can be somewhat client- and cmdline-dependent.

Comment: Royce, thank u for the reply. Yes the client and server platforms are Ubuntu 14.04.